# Connecting MVVMCross Portable connect to WCF DataService. Is it possible?

Tags: wcf-data-services, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I need your advice people. I am writing an engineering work project in VS2012 about used car dealership. I have a SQL Database, WCF DataService, WPF application (which is connected succesfuly to WCF) and wanted to create Mobile version for it too. I chose MVVMCross Portable to create Mono For Android and WP7 app with one core. And I have problems here with connecting to my WCF DataService from mobile portable core like:

> Unable to add a service reference to the specified OData feed because
>   WCF Data Services is not installed for this target framework. To install
>   a supported version of WCF Data Services, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=253653.

I searched on the internet and it seems that Portable Class Library doesn't support the WCF Data Service yet. I am writing this question to you in hope that there is any solution for this. If not shall I just wait?

- or perhaps I need to change my WCF Data Service to normal WCF Service that will work on mvvmcross portable but there will be a lot of work to change in app what I have in WPF done,
- or maybe I should get back to MVVMCross Master, that is without portable-class-library, but there is no support for Android to connect with Data Service.

I read a little about Simply.OData but I have no idea how to put it to work succesfuly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've connected MvvmCross applications to WCF Basic HTTP data services from all of Droid, Touch and WinPhone (never tried WinRT or WPF - but they should work too)

You are, however, correct that the WCF code will need to be different on the different platforms - this is because the code WCF uses isn't portable.

I think there are 2 basic choices about how to tackle this:

1. Wrap the WCF code behind a portable interface - an interface that deals in Portable DTO classes and that presents an interface for the Get/Send. You'll then need to write a small class for each platform which maps the portable DTO's to/from the non-portable ones. Tools like AutoMapper may help with this - I haven't tried this on MonoDroid or WinPhone though.
2. Use file-linking in your core and maintain separate library projects for each platform. For an example of this file linking approach take a look at https://github.com/Redth/WshLst/ - this was for Azure mobile services rather than WCF - but the same principals apply.

Neither of these two approaches is perfect - both put overhead into development - but both still hopefully provide you with a way to share code and build your app moving forwards.

I personally prefer approach 1 - as it provides a clean interface separating the current network stack from my app logic - and it provides me with a technical route to removing WCF and replacing it with something like WebAPI or service stack in the future.

---

In the near future, there may be a shared Portable Class library profile which supports some WCF functionality across MonoTouch and MonoDroid - but I doubt this will be available at any point soon on Wp or WinRT :/

---

I'm afraid don't know anything about Simple.OData (this it https://github.com/simplefx/Simple.OData) - I trust the guys who wrote it a lot, but I don't know how well their `dynamic` code works on WP and MonoDroid. I believe it should work on both - but there may be issues with any code that relies on `Reflection.Emit`.

---

One final point - whenever you do anything network related on WP, always try to enable GZip compression if you can - WP doesn't provide this by default.

Comment: Big thanks for your help, i appreciate it - my programing adventure is after 1 year so it is in the beginning. Regarding to approach 1 you mean, create a WCF Service (normal, not Data) in one project? So the solution for my problem is so easy. I completely forgot about possibility of creating more interfaces in WCF. Few months ago i tried it with your MVVMCrossMaster and it worked. I hope there will be no problem with Android now. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Regarding to Automap, i studied a little about it and it is very useful tool, but where shall i put it? In Core project, which i need to separate for each platform? Like Core.Android and Core.WP7?

Comment: I can't really help - especially not from so little information. Try to experiment. Try to solve problems yourself first. When you hit barriers you can always come back with new questions - but not in comments - things are too hard to read here.

Comment: @Stuart While Simple.OData does not target multiple platforms (due to Simple.Data.Core nature), a portable part of it has been recently extracts into a Simple.OData.Client and just few days ago I published first NuGet package with PCL version.

Comment: How do i enable GZip compression? By Custom Message Encoder: Compression Encoder like in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751458.aspx both on client and server side?

Comment: @lechu don't ask new questions in comments - take it to chat or to new questions. I prefer new questions

Comment: @VagifAbilov whaaaaaaat? Really? :) I'll head over to your blog and/or GitHub :)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at Simple.OData.Client. It's a portable class library (used internally but Simple.Data OData adapter) written exactly for this purpose. I even use it with MvvmCross.

It's on GitHub and has a NuGet package. Make sure you install it with "pre" option.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer. If i think clear i should install Simple.OData.Client in View layer of each platform, because of there is adapter on that layer right? I am trying to install it with command "Install-Package Simple.Data.OData -pre" on View or Core but i get "You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Silverlight,Version=v4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone71 or porta ble-win+net45+MonoAndroid16+sl40+net10+wp71'"

Comment: installing pcls into monoandroid pcls is hard - ask a new question for the details (asking a new question will make the answer more visible to Google, Bing and people with the same problem)

Comment: @lechu oops I overlooked that you need support for WP7. Simple.OData.Client supports WP8. I'll check what it takes to add WP7 support but I'm afraid you may be out of luck finding an OData client for Windows Phone 7.

Comment: @VagifAbilov OK it worked :) i copied my WP7 project and sucessfuly upgraded to WP8. I have installed Simple.Odata.Client pack with -pre option but still i can't install this on Android. I have referenced to Simple.NExtLib.Net40 project what i have found on gib but here i get a warning. Haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Lechu, glad it worked for WP8. I may need to do some configuration tricks to make it install on Android: the source is compatible but NuGet packaging may need more work, it's in the plan. In the meantime you can grab sources directly from GitHub and reference them. You won't need NExtLib.