# How to enable GZIP on WP in PortableClassLibrary (MVVMCross)?? WP can not connect to WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I need a little help in enabling GZip compression on Windows Phone in portable library in MVVMCross.

I have WCF Service and i try to connect with WP but after a few seconds i have exception that remote server is NotFound. I tried to connect by silverlight and it works fine. After many hours i guess - thanks to fiddler - that my problem is in compression, data are compressed and WP don't read it. I also tried to turn off compression in IIS configuration, but the problem is still on - (checked with fiddler, Accept-Encoding: gzip,delate,sdch; Content-Encoding:none). It is with any default WindowsPhone client with any default WCF Service created by new project.

Any ideas are more than welcome.
Thanks in advance

My code is:

> WcfMobileServiceClient db = new WcfMobileServiceClient();
>
> db.CheckConnectionCompleted += (sender, args) =>{};
>
> db.CheckConnectionAsync("test");

UPDATE: The problem with connecting WindowsPhone to WCF was in emulator of WP8 on VS2012 - it has a isolated network. More about it is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Is WP requesting compression (using Accept-Encoding)? If it's not requesting it, IIS shouldn't be sending compressed data. Could you add your request/response headers to the question?

Comment: I can't see it with fiddler because it doesn't show - don't know why - logs were from SilverLight. My problem is with any WP project and any WCF project. Updated with code

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is independent of PCL and independent of MvvmCross - work out how to solve it in WP with WCF first, and then worry about adding an interface or abstraction layer to consume the compression code in a PCL.

---

AFAIK, this is only a problem on WindowsPhone - I believe Droid, Touch, WPF and RT all support compression without additional code needed.

However, the networking stack in the Compact Framework in WindowsPhone does not support GZip - so you have to either not request GZip data (which is bad for network performance) or you have to provide your own decompression implementation.

In a non-PCL project providing compression support is fairly trivial - there are several solutions available - e.g.

- http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/windows-phone-gzip-support-by-morten/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2012/04/19/quot-if-i-have-seen-further-it-is-by-standing-on-the-shoulders-of-giants-quot-an-alternate-implementation-of-http-gzip-decompression-for-windows-phone.aspx
- and others

Once you get this working, then you should be able to consume this in a PCL project using a technique like Dependency Injection (see your earlier question [Connecting MVVMCross Portable connect to WCF DataService. Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875344/connecting-mvvmcross-portable-connect-to-wcf-dataservice-is-it-possible))

Answer (score -1):

Check out GZipWebClient for Windows Phone.

https://github.com/dotMorten/SharpGIS.GZipWebClient